# Оптимизация размера изображений (IMagick)

Tags: imagemagick, php, оптимизация, изображения

Хотелось бы узнать. Как можно максимально сжать размер изображения (кб). При перезаписи или ресайзе ?

Вот к примеру такой простой код есть

```
 $image = new Imagick($tmp_name);
 $image->thumbnailImage(600,0);
 $image->writeImage($name);
```

Можно что-то в него добавить что б на выходе как можно меньше занимала картинка?

Заметил одну неприятную особенность. Иногда, если изменить картинку с помощью imagick может получится так что исходная картинка занимает больше чем та что была в начале (делаю перезапись или ресайз в меньшую сторону), так же иногда GD делает картинки меньше по размеру(кб).

Comment: насколько понимаю, можно изменить уровень сжатия

http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php

Comment: могу предложить хитрый хак. Размер изображения делаем на порядок больше требуемого, но качество jpeg выставляем порядка 80. При выводе изображения принудительно указываем требуемые высоту и ширину. При такой фишке качество выводимого(показываемого) изображения визуально не будет отличаться но размер будет намного меньше.